# Open graph meta tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I use Facebook application (shortstack) to make my page.
I want to Personalize publication when I share it with short URL.
I have test to create a open graph meta tags but it's don't work .

Answer (score 6):

You need to put opengraph meta tags in your page like

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
<meta property="og:description"
      content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
               a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
               threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
               weapons."/>
```

example found it here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

You also need to change the top  tag to

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

And then it should work fine :)

To debug your page and see if you correctly implemented opengraph tags use the debugger tool here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Hope that helps

Comment: For simple testing, you can paste your html snippet and publish online with this tool http://www.golery.com/posthtml then try with facebook debgger developers.facebook.com/tools/debug


Note that facebook cache the image, so you need to ask facebook debugger to refresh several times.