# Specify caption when posting Custom Story via Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

When posting a custom story via the Graph API, is it possible to specify/change the caption of the attachment when I post the story to the user's account, i.e. on the fly?

Right now it defaults to the name of the app posting the action ("Action Center - Scale Review" in the screenshot).

I see in [the docs for stories](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories#attachments) that I can specify up to 4 captions via the UI. But it's not clear to me when these take affect; for example, in the screenshot, I have 4 captions specified for that story - but none are showing. Plus, that's not on the fly/dynamic which is what I'm looking for.

It doesn't look like passing "caption" as an option when posting the action has any effect, nor does a "og:caption" param on the custom object.

I can specify the caption when posting a link via other methods - [for example, when publishing a post on a users wall, I can specify the caption for the link.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed/#pubfields)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether those “caption” fields are shown any more for simple objects (the docs might be outdated on this). Even if they are, you can not populate them dynamically, apart from using object property placeholders.

I think you best bet is to use the description (the “Heres a A Demo […]” line in your screenshot) to place the information you want to publish. You can create objects “on the fly” using the [Object API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#objectapi). If you want individual objects on a “per user” basis, then this would be the way to go.

Comment: The `caption` fields still seem to show up on most place I've seen posts. It makes total sense that you wouldn't be able to edit the caption dynamically; that it would always be the app name. However, when posting a link via a generic post to a user's wall (`/me/feed`), you can specify the caption to be whatever you like. This is why I am looking for an official answer. The `Story Attachment` seems to be missing an attribute (`caption`) that I can specify when it comes to other posts to the users wall.

Comment: Creating an object on the fly, or on a "per user" basis, wouldn't change anything with this scenario. I can specify the `description` with `og:` tags at the source of the link I'm posting as the `Story Attachment`, no need to create new objects for each attachment.

Answer (score 0):

To make the captions dynamic you have to add curly braces : example :

```
by {}
```

When typed "{" it will show a drop down with your custom objects and you can use your objects to make captions dynamic.

However there is a huge limitation of bringing these captions into new lines.

Answer (score -1):

It's clearly stated in the documentation link you provided.

Here's the code:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/me/feed',
  array (
    'message'       => 'This is a test message',
    'link'          => '',
    'picture'       => '',
    'name'          => '',
    'caption'       => '',
    'description'   => '',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

When you click on the arrow next to "link" in the Facebook Docs page, you'll see the other options related to the "link".

Comment: What you posted is for a regular post on the user's wall. As the question title states, I'm looking for specifying a caption for a custom story. The link is seen as a `Story Attachment` for a custom story, not a link.

Comment: Then, it's probably a duplicate of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172183/open-graph-meta-tags
There's only 2 ways to publish a "FEED". You can do that programmatically (using the Facebook API) or the user can "like" or "share" a link on a specific page/section and it'll post the "OpenGraph properties" written on that page.

Comment: If you're using custom stories for a Facebook App, you should use the OpenGraph meta tags: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories#objecttypes-properties
Also, you should use any of the Action Types mentioned here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/
Or you can create your own Action Types from the Facebook App settings page

Comment: There is no `og:caption` property available, and rightfully so - the `og` properties are for the page, not the application sharing it. As you stated, I can pass a `caption` parameter when posting a link to the a user's feed. The `caption` parameter seems to be missing when posting a `story attachment` to a user's feed, which is why I'm looking for an authoritative reference here. None of the docs you provided tell me about providing _dynamic_ captions for story attachments.

Comment: There's no "og:caption" for the Custom Stories. You need to create a [custom property](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories#objecttypes-customproperties). You assign the "type" as "string" and you name it "caption".

Comment: If I add a `custom property` of `og:caption`, I get a `Sorry, og_caption is reserved and can't be used. Try something more descriptive.` error. So I created a custom property just named `caption`. I go to the settings for the story` to set the caption =  `{campaign.caption}` as [stated in the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories#attachments), but when I make the post, that caption isn't read. Am I missing a setting somewhere, or do I need to pass a review, to make that caption stick?

Comment: Name it something else. "image_caption" for instance. I don't think you need a "permission" for a custom post type: [Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2). As far as I know, the permissions are directly related to the user's actions and the user's data. I don't think it includes an App "Custom Property"

Comment: Do you have an idea of why it's not showing up as the caption then when it's set as the caption?

Comment: I have no idea, but if it's a "reserved word", you might not be allowed to use it.