# rendering open graph meta tags in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, metadata, meta-tags

I am trying to find some information about how to render/display Open Graph Meta Tags on my Wordpress page.

What i found there is a lot of data how to set up this for social media, 
[Open graph meta tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172183/open-graph-meta-tags)
but nothing how to  read and display in Wordpress.

What i want to do is to render/display news/article and display in the same way as twitter card but on my Wordpress page.

example. i have link -  http://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-us-canada-42589965/explosion-as-two-planes-collide-in-toronto-pearson

WP reads link meta and display it similar way as on twitter
https://twitter.com/BBCWorld/status/949624397182234625

Any idea how to do this?
I hope that there is a way to do this in PHP and WP.

Thank you for help and resources.

Best

Comment: your metas will be static and similar for all pages?

Comment: i dont think so. think about different web articles, blogs etc. exactly as in twitter and FB. Any web with og. metas. so i scan them and render as twitter does. only articles and blogs. best

Comment: try to use this solution for your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11075694/8053001

Comment: I am not trying to add dynamic Facebook og meta tags. I want to read and process them.